# How do I bind cell value to a specific property on an object?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, binding, wpftoolkit

I have a `DataTable` that is populated at the cell level with the following type:

```
public class GridCell
{
    public string Value { get; set}
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

I've bound the DataTable to a WPF Toolkit DataGrid, but the cells are coming up empty. How do I tell the `DataGrid` to look in the `Value` property of my `GridCell` type for the cell contents?

Binding snippet:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Table}" />
```

Comment: Are you assigning the itemsource property of the grid to GridCell collection.Can you post your binding code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the limited info in your question I am guessing that your data table contains columns of custom types which I would not recommend since it will make your code so much more complicated. But if you decide to go that way you can implement your custom column type to handle that. I haven't tried that, but this link looks promising: [Bind DataTable to WPF DataGrid using DataGridTemplateColumn Programatically](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/8b2e94b7-3c44-4642-8acc-851de5285062)

You can also use value converters to achieve the same thing. Below sample pass the column index as parameter but you could also pass which property you are interested in as well using some format (0-Value for example, meaning column 0, property Value).

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="GridCellDemo.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
    xmlns:GridCellDemo="clr-namespace:GridCellDemo"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <GridCellDemo:CellConverter x:Key="CellConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Controls:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 0" Binding="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource CellConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" />
                <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 1" Binding="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource CellConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" />
            </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </Controls:DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace GridCellDemo
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
        }

        public DataTable Data
        {
            get
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col0", typeof(GridCell)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(GridCell)));

                DataRow row0 = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.Add(row0);
                row0["Col0"] = new GridCell() { Value = "R0C0" };
                row0["Col1"] = new GridCell() { Value = "R0C1" };

                DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.Add(row1);
                row1["Col0"] = new GridCell() { Value = "R1C0" };
                row1["Col1"] = new GridCell() { Value = "R1C1" };

                return dt;
            }
        }
    }

    public class GridCell
    {
        public string Value { get; set;  }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class CellConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DataRowView drv = value as DataRowView;
            if (drv == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            int columnIndex = int.Parse(parameter.ToString());
            GridCell gridCell = drv[columnIndex] as GridCell;
            return gridCell.Value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A converter sounds do-able. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridCellList}"`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridCellList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Guid" Binding="{Binding Path=Guid}" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Rows and columns are appearing with the current binding. It's the cells that are empty.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you use DataTable. Can't you directly bind Collection of GridCell. I haven't tried binding dataTable to dataGrid.

Comment: The collection isn't the issue. I need to bind to a specific property of the items within the collection.

Comment: Then u can define column for the grid Manually.